# Finding the longest string within an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have an NSArray filled with 200,000 words and I don't know the length of each word.
I need to know what is the maximum length of a word contained in that array.

For example, if my array is {"dog","person","amazing"}
The maximum length of a word contained in this array would be 7  ("amazing")

How would I do this?

Comment: There is no technique faster than simply iterating through the array and looking for the longest element.

Comment: @HotLicks see Ramy's answer

Comment: @MZimmerman6 - I'd be willing to bet that that approach is slower.

Comment: @HotLicks why do you think that? I am intrigued

Comment: Using the `@max.length` thing requires that generic code interpret those instructions.  Still has to loop, and the access to `length` is likely more indirect.  Why would you expect it to not be slower?

Comment: I was not thinking of it like that. You are probably right, but it always nicer looking to have everything in one line. I guess for 200k works we would want the fastest possible, which yes, would likely be looping

Comment: @MZimmerman6 - Actually, one shot of 200k words (vs doing that many every few seconds) is not that much, and the `@max.length` approach may be justified -- if you already know of it and understand it.  But if you have to search for it, and if it causes any confusion for you or later maintainers then the explicit iteration approach is both faster to write and more robust to maintain.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Besides all methods that imply iterating over the array, you can easily do this with `valueForKeyPath:`, using the `@max` collection operator:

```
NSNumber* maxLength= [array valueForKeyPath: @"@max.length"];
```

Comment: I'm curious as to how this works. Can you explain a little more??

Comment: @BlueMeanie This is possible because all collections implement some operators like max (spiral omitted to avoid quotes), avg, count, etc... here is the reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Answer (score 12):

You may try this

**To find the longest word length**

```
NSArray *wordList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"dog", @"person", @"amazing", nil];

int maxLen, strLen;
for(NSString *str in wordList) {
    strLen = [str length];
    if ( strLen > maxLen) {
        maxLen = strLen;
    } 
}
NSLog(@"Longest Word Length = %d", maxLen);
```

**To find the longest word**

```
NSArray *wordList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"dog", @"person", @"amazing", nil];

NSString *longestWord = nil;
for(NSString *str in wordList) {
    if (longestWord == nil || [str length] > [longestWord length]) {
        longestWord = str;
    }
}
NSLog(@"Longest Word = %@", longestWord);
```

Comment: Fast enumeration seems to be faster than Key-Value Coding, but I would perhaps keep the longest *length* instead of the longest *string*, to avoid that `[longestWord length]` is computed repeatedly.

Comment: Or store both, if you want to avoid `[longestWord length]` if you want to avoid multiple calls but you still want the actual word at the end.